# OMP SIMD logical AND on unsigned long long

Tags: c++, performance, bit-manipulation, openmp, simd

I have been playing around with SIMD OMP instructions and I am not getting the compiler to emit `ANDPS` in my scenario.

What I'm trying to do:

- This is an implementation of this [problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/RRFRNDS) (tldr: find pair of users with a common friend). My approach is to pack 64 bits (whether somebody is a friend or not) into an `unsigned long long`.
- My SIMD approach: Take `AND` between two vectors of relationship and `reduce` with a `OR` which nicely fits the [reduction pattern](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html#x140-5810002.19.5.1) of OMP.

g++ instructions (on a 2019 intel i-7 macbookPro):

`g++-11 friends.cpp -S -O3 -fopenmp -fsanitize=address -Wshadow -Wall -march=native --std=c++17;`

My implementation below

```cpp
#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>

#include "iostream"

#include <cmath>

#include <numeric>

typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;

using namespace std;


ull find_sol(vector<vector<ull>> & input_data, int q) {

    bool not_friend = false;
    ull cnt = 0;
    int size_arr = (int) input_data[0].size();

    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i) // from these friends
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < q; ++j) // to these friends
        {
            int step = j/64;
            int remainder = j - 64*step;
        
            not_friend = (input_data[i].at(step) >> remainder) % 2 == 0;
            
            if(not_friend){   
                bool counter = false;
                
                vector<ull> & v1 = input_data[i];
                vector<ull> & v2 = input_data[j];

                #pragma omp simd reduction(|:counter)
                for (int c = 0; c < size_arr; ++c)
                {
                    __asm__ ("entry");
                    counter |= (v1[c] & v2[c])>0;
                    __asm__ ("exit");
                }

                if(counter>0)
                    cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt << 1;
}


int main(){

    int q;
    cin >> q;
    vector<vector<ull>> input_data(q,vector<ull>(1 + q/64,0ULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
    {

        string s;
        cin >> s;

        for (int j = 0; j < 1 + q/64; ++j)
        {
            string str = s.substr(j*64,64);
            reverse(str.begin(),str.end());
            ull ul = std::stoull(str,nullptr,2);
            input_data.at(i).at(j) = ul;
        }
        
    }

    cout << find_sol(input_data,q) << endl;


    }
```

Looking at the assembly inside the loop, I would expect some SIMD instructions (specifically `andps`) but I can't see them. What's preventing my compiler to emit them? Also, is there a way for the compiler to emit a warning re:what's wrong (would be very helpful)?

```
    entry
# 0 "" 2
    cmpb    $0, (%rbx)
    jne L53
    movq    (%r8), %rdx
    leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdi
    addq    %rdi, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %r15
    shrq    $3, %r15
    cmpb    $0, (%r15,%rcx)
    jne L54
    cmpb    $0, (%r11)
    movq    (%rdx), %rdx
    jne L55
    addq    (%r9), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, %r15
    shrq    $3, %r15
    cmpb    $0, (%r15,%rcx)
    jne L56
    andq    (%rdi), %rdx
    movzbl  (%r12), %edx
    setne   %dil
    cmpb    %r13b, %dl
    jg  L21
    testb   %dl, %dl
    jne L57
L21:
    orb %dil, -32(%r10)
```

EDIT 1:
Following Peter 1st and 2nd suggestion, I moved the marker out of the loop and I replaced the binarization by a simple `OR`. I'm still not getting SIMD instructions though:

```cpp
           ull counter = 0;
                
                vector<ull> & v1 = input_data[i];
                vector<ull> & v2 = input_data[j];


                __asm__ ("entry" :::);

                #pragma omp simd reduction(|:counter)
                for (int c = 0; c < size_arr; ++c)
                {
                    counter |= v1[c] & v2[c];
                }
                __asm__ ("exit" :::);

                if(counter!=0)
                    cnt++;
```

Comment: In recent GCC, non-empty Basic Asm statements like `__asm__ ("entry");` have an implicit `::: "memory"` clobber, making it impossible for the compiler to combine array accesses across iterations.  Maybe try `__asm__ ("entry" :::);` if you really want these markers.  (Extended asm without a memory clobber).

Comment: Also, why are you booleanizing with `(v1[c] & v2[c])>0;`?  That would need SSE4.1 `pcmpeqq` to auto-vectorize, vs. just OR and then check `counter` for `!=0` that can horizontally OR and eventually just check a single scalar uint64_t for being non-zero.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I updated the code based on your suggestions but I'm still not getting SIMD instructions. Let me know if you have other suggestion! Thx

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` why? That makes it harder for the compiler to optimize things...

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Indeed, it vectorizes ok without that and without the `asm` statements.  (The OpenMP vectorization is insane, using `vpmuldq` (index multiply?) and `vpgatherqq` with GCC11.2, but plain `-ftree-vectorize` vectorization is normal.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed. I am not very familiar with openmp simd, but that looks worth a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem: `asm`**.  In recent GCC, non-empty Basic Asm statements like `__asm__ ("entry");` have an implicit `::: "memory"` clobber, making it impossible for the compiler to combine array accesses across iterations.  Maybe try `__asm__ ("entry" :::);` if you really want these markers.  (Extended asm without a memory clobber).

Or better, use better tools for looking at compiler output, such as the Godbolt compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/) which lets you right click on a source line and go to the corresponding asm.  (Optimization can make this a bit wonky, so sometimes you have to find the asm and mouseover it to make sure it comes from that source line.)

See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

**Second problem:** `-fsanitize=address` makes it harder for the compiler to optimize.  I only looked at GCC output without that option.

---

#### Vectorizing the OR reduction

After fixing those showstoppers:

You're forcing the compiler to booleanize to an 8-bit `bool` inside the inner loop, instead of just reducing the integer AND results with `|=` into a variable of the same type.  (Which you check once after the loop.)  This is probably part of why GCC has a hard time; it often makes a mess with different-sized integer types when it vectorizes at all.

`(v1[c] & v2[c]) > 0;` would need SSE4.1 `pcmpeqq`vs. just SIMD OR in the loop and check `counter` for `!=0` after the loop.  (You had `bool counter`, which was really surprising given `counter>0` as a semantically weird way to check an unsigned value for non-zero.  Even more unexpected for a `bool`.)

After changing that, GCC auto-vectorizes the way I expected without OpenMP, if you use `-O3` (which includes `-ftree-vectorize`).  It of course uses with `vpand`, not `vandps`, since FP booleans have lower throughput on some CPUs.  (You didn't say what `-march=native` is for you; if you only had AVX1, e.g. on Sandybridge, then `vandps` is plausible.)

```
                ull counter = 0;
                // #pragma omp simd reduction(|:counter)
                for (int c = 0; c < size_arr; ++c)
                {
                    //__asm__ ("entry");
                    counter |= (v1[c] & v2[c]);
                    //__asm__ ("exit");
                }

                if(counter != 0)
                    cnt++;
```

From the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOXUYBVAM7YACgA8QAcgAMM8gCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIT37yYzqiIEG1bPUwBhdOwCuAW3oheADnI3MAGQJ6bAA5VwAjbFIQAGYANnIAB3QRYkt6B2c3D28klIsGAKDQlwiouJNsM3z6JiJWUiIM13cvCqq02vqiQpDwyJj4kTqGpqzWoa6e4tKBgEoTdCdSVC4ZPWjA1GccAGptaLsAN2xzMn3cbTkAQXXN7ew9g45gMmIkF3PLm90N%2Bi2nXZ6XSWIakbCsD66XRfW5/e6POyoFysIhIT7XWH/QEHeiuSIEHTRC4Y65EACeCWwOBoO3YDGAtPptPY%2B0MpIpVOwNKc9BSwCCmEZmiFDKc7BZ0TZN2uThSwvoEOwIgSrBWOyGmFZMJl4p2NECmAA%2BiJHBBjqdSPsjicSJaDmKJRciXtdLEdoEEk4iIbMCjWOR3YwdgBHWZ7ADsUq%2BOxjOzC6EcO3o6G9NFIBF8jwAInqOGItddYzsHTtUEH9jm5AWrkXAkR1QQAF7YQ31UjZnYQOthj1en1%2B7QAVn0VcHWYAdClmxBZtXo7G6O2u0GCB2q5L3QiQ6yXYYDAQwwB6Q960joFw7VFKh5pjO2ETzmPaSOPot6sidus7JQdghGbg7j%2BVrbhuRhGEoR4niQl5INep53pgD6Fm%2BT4vshKG1kGQzYAkHZKIesS8NWGFvl%2BYLIgakR4TsAC0OyEQAVNhCTERhr4kcmqbppmFafvQnrer6dRDvof5juOKIQMxYafM65GsJRpAybog47Lo2a8euUokUW7EYQQNAQJxhq3r4s6RrGek6Ts5q2laDrnC6bqHNwv78X2QmsCJYlZqx1lFrZZz2uKjl6M56m8b2gkDsOShDr5krajW/lFiWGA8kQVGaX5KU7Me6wJKQrDAMiOznrhKQuIKYKYE45hpBAz52GgiyMJEs7obli58fWqBrjufXAVOLZtjuYEGKgHXJblEbaTNb7HoarYiC4S2dkCNhEKQZJArOiWdfNpatZl7ZNbxZoAcOOhjk5NnQld8V7XNh0xoty2rYa61QtgkjELtOUpc%2BvkktNuUGRA6Vte2YBgJpU0vbGZZEONhj7aDJFA1ZEbA6DmOdWCRBLPQpblgcwEAWjePStTX4UfQM7PlGnVfsGOWoIEjxOrgIHPTZNpBdaFr2SFRKOVF/Z1BAwbkIFdp2A5RIQK5RghgR/ByEIfh%2BLMT1JUW3XLvWq7ZRuxsHDzu5GAer6M1joKBAyD5oyR7PE7J3NO0z6MLh%2Bhvfv1G5AebysGKrhFjQY4Hw2xaHeyh9vCqCHYiJOThhKCEBKAxhHkIRusHRhYLHKQYhSVt44RMAgQziY5e%2BDO%2Bdx2%2BJZisnRCYCAIBDIs4plxQuLigkW3kLojcpeLnkSUQXazFPmcydEOZigDlnhjjGOdVTr7pfWVrAfqtjGqaE9%2BuQoYIsBvgSlGa8yPM7CyIOijuPIijoLIdgo%2BqizLA86zcIoIgsgFA63IAAaxAIObg45dDhmiLA3QchPC8EHOGTw5QH4yF4IoFwPA5ByHIC/BQ5B34yEUCIEABCgGv3mHAWAKAMAuASAQTgFAqAQ3Kiw/owBuDcF0AIFhJ0KEQDCMAxQYRAj1DJLIAB5BGEuE2gAeXoOwaRr9yA4GRJoTgYiNEEDBPVY4FD1E/ROF6VYsi6yVF0ewAgYQirbQcDgGRgD0y4JkAA%2BYNB1DABEAANQzAAd0UZSF%2BsjBDMDYDovgAgGBEFEBIaQ6iVD8PUJoNAKM1B2IoZAeY6Ah5pGMTRAA6hwdgtFFHRFonQUJTDaLImWGiReIgwFknUGAh4NENQVn5E4FG3BwwxhojQLa2BsA0Vlk2SIEzIjxnzIvVywz8lEBooEOg5DKg2jSNYWwox3DcB8LYKYfQoioMSMkVIDA9mqFyJc%2BgxySj9DOaYLZDBOgjEcM0VQLz6pvOGN0QIvRHmnPDLXLo1yDkTAaA8mYqD5gmiWCsHg99H7P10aQyQnhYg0UIjsYAqA%2Bq8JgZ2T%2BkcDABnwMQD8/8AwOCYVw06PxR6ALEaA2CrAcBRBrhArw45wyun5eGAAnNwQcvBdDcBzpg7B5BcHcHwYQ9FshyGUPINQkBKKZC6BwSAfl45YjCvgV4IVKC%2BDhniEQt%2Byq1WsvIHQ5AIBFhEAEpQagjDmGsJAPwqkVKogHIiSwDgXAYkRISVIXRgSioJBcZqp%2Bir1GkMUV6ASZUaSYuxbi/FhLoHqQgHSj1WUmWzBZTQ%2BY7LOXUE1TK3BsDxzwLkAaqBcgxWeEHD8C1SqyEmFVequ%2BmrohooTda3toDi4pCsLwIAA) (which you should use instead of littering your code with `asm` statements)

```
# g++ 11.2 -O3 -march=skylake   **without** OpenMP
.L7:                              # the vector part of the inner-most loop
        vmovdqu ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        vpand   ymm0, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax]
        add     rax, 32
        vpor    ymm1, ymm1, ymm0
        cmp     rax, r8
        jne     .L7
        vextracti128    xmm0, ymm1, 0x1
        vpor    xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vpsrldq xmm1, xmm0, 8
        ...  (horizontal OR reduction of that one SIMD vector, eventually vmovq to RAX)
```

### GCC OpenMP does vectorize, but badly / weirdly

With OpenMP, there is a vectorized version of the loop, but it sucks a lot, doing shuffles and gather loads, and storing results into a local buffer which it later reads.  I don't know OpenMP that well, but unless you're using it wrong, this is a major missed optimization.  Possibly it's scaling a loop counter with multiplies instead of incrementing a pointer, which is just horrible.

([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOXUYBVAM7YACgA8QAcgAMM8gCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIT37yYzqiIEG1bPUwBhdOwCuAW3oheADnI3MAGQJ6bAA5VwAjbFIQAGYANnIAB3QRYkt6B2c3D28klIsGAKDQlwiouJNsM3z6JiJWUiIM13cvCqq02vqiQpDwyJj4kTqGpqzWoa6e4tKBgEoTdCdSVC4ZPWjA1GccAGptaLsAN2xzMn3cbTkAQXXN7ew9g45gMmIkF3PLm90N%2Bi2nXZ6XSWIakbCsD66XRfW5/e6POyoFysIhIT7XWH/QEHeiuSIEHTRC4Y65EACeCWwOBoO3YDGAtPptPY%2B0MpIpVOwNKc9BSwCCmEZmiFDKc7BZ0TZN2uThSwvoEOwIgSrBWOyGmFZMJl4p2NECmAA%2BiJHBBjqdSPsjicSJaDmKJRciXtdLEdoEEk4iIbMCjWOR3YwdgBHWZ7ADsUq%2BOxjOzC6EcO3o6G9NFIBF8jwAInqOGItddYzsHTtUEH9jm5AWrkXAkR1QQAF7YQ31UjZnYQOthj1en1%2B7QAVn0VcHWYAdClmxBZtXo7G6O2u0GCB2q5L3QiQ6yXYYDAQwwB6Q960joFw7VFKh5pjO2ETzmPaSOPot6sidus7JQdghGbg7j%2BVrbhuRhGEoR4niQl5INep53pgD6Fm%2BT4vshKG1kGQzYAkHZKIesS8NWGFvl%2BYLIgakR4TsAC0OyEQAVNhCTERhr4kcmqbppmFafvQnrer6dRDvof5juOKIQMxYafM65GsJRpAybog47Lo2a8euUokUW7EYQQNAQJxhq3r4s6RrGek6Ts5q2laDrnC6bqHNwv78X2QmsCJYlZqx1lFrZZz2uKjl6M56m8b2gkDsOShDr5krajW/lFiWGA8kQVGaX5KUutECSkKwwDIjs564SkLiCmCmBOOYaQQM%2BdhoIsjCRLO6G5YufH1qga47r1wFTi2bY7mBBioO1yW5RG2nTW%2Bx6Gq2IguItnZAjYRCkGSQKzolHVzaWLWZe2jW8WaAHDjoY5OTZ0KXfFu2zQdMYLUtK2GmtULYJIxA7TlKXPr5JJTblBkQOlrXtmAYCaZNz2xmWRBjYYe0gyRgNWRGQMgxjHVgkQSz0KW5YHMBAGo7j0pU1%2BFH0DOz5Rh1X7BjlqCBI8Tq4CBT02TaQXWha9khUSjlRf2dQQMG5CBXadgOUSECuUYIYEfwchCH4fizI9SVFl1y71qu2UbkbBzc7uRgHq%2BDOY6CgQMg%2BqMkWzROyVzjuM2jC4fgb359RuQFm0rBgq4Ro0GOBcNsWhXsoXbwqgh2IiTk4YSghASgMYR5CETr%2B0YWCxykGIUmbeOETAIEM4mGXvgznnsdviWYpJ0QmAgCAQyLOKpcULi4oJJt5C6A3KVi55ElEF2syTxnMnRDmYr/ZZ4bY%2BjHWU6%2B6X1lawH6rYxqmuPfrkKGCLAb4EpRqvMjzOwsiDoo7jyIo6CyHYyPqosywPOs3CKEQWQChtbkAANYgEHNwccuhwzRBgboOQnheCDnDJ4co98ZC8EUC4Hgcg5DkGfgocgb8ZCKBECAfBgCX7zDgLAFAGAXAJAIJwCgVBwZlWYf0YA3BuC6AEMw465CIBhCAYoMIgR6hklkP/cgDCXAbQAPL0HYFIl%2B5AcDIk0JwUR6iCBgjqscchajvonC9KsGRdZKg6PYAQMIhUtoOBwNIgB6YcEyH/vMGg6hgAiAAGoZgAO4KMpM/GRghmBsG0XwAQDAiCiAkNINRKg%2BHqE0GgZGahbHkMgPMdAg80hGJogAdQ4OwWiCjoi0ToCExhtFkTLDRAvEQoCyTqFAQ8GiGoKz8icMjbg4YYw0RoJtbA2AaIyybJEcZkR4z5gXq5IZeSiA0UCHQMhlQbRpGsLYUY7gYE%2BFsFMPoURPDxFyKkBguyQD7POdUI5JR%2BinLaJshgnQRiOGaNc6Izy6qvOGN0QIvQHknMGP8q5Pwa6TEBdMR5sR5gmiWCsHgd8H5Px0SQyQpyaKER2MAVAvUeHQM7B/COBgAz4GIB%2BP%2BAYHCMM4SdH4I8AGiJAbBVgOAojV3AV4cc4ZXR8vDAATm4IOXguhuDZwwVg8gODuB4IIei2QZCKHkCocAlFMhdDYJAHy8csQhVwK8IK5BfBwzxEIa/JVqqWXkFocgEAiwiACUoNQBhTCWHXJ8IQW0qhwksA4FwaJ4T4lSB0QEwqCRnEasfgqtRJCFFegEqVGkmLYjYt4Li/FOxCXqQgLS91WVGWzGZdQ%2BYbKOXUA1dKnBMDxxwLkPqyBchRWeEHD8c1irSEmBVWq2%2BGrohorjVa3tICi4pCsLwIAA))

```
# g++ 11.2 -Wall -O3 -fopenmp -march=skylake -std=gnu++17
                     # with the #pragma uncommented
.L10:
        vmovdqa ymm0, ymm3
        vpermq  ymm0, ymm0, 216
        vpshufd ymm1, ymm0, 80      # unpack for 32x32 => 64-bit multiplies?
        vpmuldq ymm1, ymm1, ymm4
        vpshufd ymm0, ymm0, 250
        vpmuldq ymm0, ymm0, ymm4
        vmovdqa ymm7, ymm6           # ymm6 = set1(-1) outside the loop, gather mask
        add     rsi, 64
        vpaddq  ymm1, ymm1, ymm5
        vpgatherqq      ymm2, QWORD PTR [0+ymm1*1], ymm7
        vpaddq  ymm0, ymm0, ymm5
        vmovdqa ymm7, ymm6
        vpgatherqq      ymm1, QWORD PTR [0+ymm0*1], ymm7
        vpand   ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi-32]      # memory source = one array
        vpand   ymm1, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsi-64]

        vpor    ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsp+64]     # OR with old contents of local buffer
        vpor    ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        vpaddd  ymm3, ymm3, ymm4
        vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rsp+32], ymm1           # and store back into it.
        vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rsp+64], ymm0
        cmp     r9, rsi
        jne     .L10

        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rsp+16]       # outer loop tail
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rsp+20], edi
        je      .L7
```

This buffer of 64 bytes is read at the top of `.L7` (an outer loop)

```
.L7:
        vmovdqa ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsp+32]
        vpor    ymm1, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [rsp+64]
        vextracti128    xmm0, ymm1, 0x1
        vpor    xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vpsrldq xmm1, xmm0, 8
        vpor    xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vmovq   rsi, xmm0

        cmp     rsi, 1                   # sets CF unless RSI=0
        sbb     r13, -1                  # R13 -= -1 +CF    i.e. increment if CF=0
```

IDK if there's a way to hand-hold the compiler into making better asm; perhaps with pointer-width loop counters?

GCC5.4 `-O3 -fopenmp -march=haswell -std=gnu++17` makes sane asm, with just `vpand` / `vpor` and an array index increment in the loop.  The stuff outside the loop is a bit different with OpenMP vs. plain vectorization, with OpenMP using vector store / scalar reload for the horizontal OR reduction of the final vector.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for your thorough response and pointers to resources. I was not aware of them so it will go a long way. Thanks again!